# Is there something called empty coalescing operator like Null coalescing operator

Tags: php, function

PHP 7 adds the [null coalesce operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op):

```
// Fetches the value of $_GET['number'] and returns 'nonumber -NULL'
// if it does not exist.
$username = $_GET['number'] ?? 'No Number';
// This is equivalent to:
$username = isset($_GET['number']) ? $_GET['number'] : 'No Number';
```

Is there something for empty also?

Looking for something like,

```
/ Fetches the value of $_GET['number'] and returns '0' Empty
// if it does not empty.
$username = $_GET['number'] ?? 'no number or number is 0 or empty';
```

Comment: I'm also looking for it, but it probably doesn't exist. The workaround is: `$username = isset($_GET['number']) && $_GET['number'] != '' ? $_GET['number'] : 'no value or value is empty';`

Answer (score 3):

Yes, thanks to type coercion [the short ternary operator `?:`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)

Comment: But this doesn't check if the array key actually exists, right? `$_GET['number'] ?: 'something'` will trigger an error if the query string is empty, unlike `??`.

Comment: @jerome2710, correct.